# Am I missing something for vue router transitions?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to have a transition between my components in Vue, this is my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Go to home</router-link>
    <router-link to="Register">Go to register</router-link>
    <transition name="fade">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s;
  }
  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

However, the transition is not working at all. It correctly switches from component to component, but without transition.

I've read the Vue and Vue Router docs, and as far as I know I'm doing exactly what the docs are saying. Anyone knows what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: It's been a while since I last used transitions, but I think it reuses components whenever it can. Whenever that happens, the transition does not happen. In your case, it would re-use `router-view`. I think you can prevent that by adding a `:key="..."` with for example the route name to force it to use different elements.

Comment: @Sumurai8 do I have to add that to the router-links?

Comment: It would be on the router-view, but after testing it real quickly it seems that it *should* work without the key: https://codesandbox.io/s/ql977m6zpq?fontsize=14

Comment: For some reason it's not working in my project, I created a sandbox of it, would REALLY appriciate if you could check it out man, https://codesandbox.io/s/9l9qvl54n4?fontsize=14

Comment: @Sumurai8 Forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 2):

Something defines the `.fade-enter` and `.fade-appear` classes. You can see this happening if you have a link that calls the debugger after one tick, and inspect the applied styling:

```
stopThings () {
  this.$router.push({
    name: 'Login'
  });

  this.$nextTick(() => {
    debugger;
  });
}
```

Because the initial state is incorrect, the transition does not do anything.

Rename your transition and your transition classes to literally anything else, e.g. `myfade` and your transition works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The transitions, as far as I can see from the code shared, looks fine. It could be that the transitions are happening outside of the view. During the transition, both elements are visible

here is an example of adding a wrapper with relative and absolute positionsing

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Go to home</router-link>
    <router-link to="Register">Go to register</router-link>
    <div class="content">
      <transition name="fade">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.content {
  position: relative;
}
.content > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

[image: Edit Router example (SO)]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it and for some reason it's not working in my local project. I created a sandbox of it and would really appriciate if you could have a look at it: https://codesandbox.io/s/9l9qvl54n4?fontsize=14

Comment: This is an `ant-design-vue` specific issue. The css from the dependency is causing a conflict. Try commenting out `import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css'` and you'll see it is working.